# Warning TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated

Tags: mysql

Once again I need your help:) . I am new to mysql and today when I decided to do some work and start the MySQL server, I get the following warning

```
"[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated".
```

I know I should change something somewhere but I don't know where... I'm trying to start MySQL server with executing mysqld file in bin directory. I would be very grateful if someone manage to explain me why MySQL server does not want to start and what can I do... Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using `mysql.*` libraries?

Comment: Well I've downloaded MySQL Community Server which is, I believe, a portable MySQL server that does not need to be installed. I get this error while trying to run MySQL from CMD. I believe that I use MySQL libraries. Basically I am trying to connect it with Java but when I decided to play around with it today, it gave me this warning :(

Comment: I can't even "re install" it by replacing the old extracted MySQL folder with a fresh one :( .

Comment: Read my answer; that looks like the problem, not uninstalling it.

Comment: all mysql_.* families are deprecated use PDO/ mysqli and also provides full details so we can solve your issue.

Comment: Well, I downloaded MySQL Community Server which is an archive and extracted it. Then I started MySQL server and with MySQL Workbench managed to access MySQL and create some tables. Later I downloaded mysql-connector-java-5.1.24 so I can connect MySQL server with Java. After that I imported that library into my Java project and that was all. Today, when I try to start MySQL server it gives me this error ...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to set [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp)

1. Append `--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=#` onto your command line.
2. Setting it in your option file my.ini / my.cnf / etc - [Option-File Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html).
3. setting it as a system variable.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused when upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.6. It looks like you have more than one version of mysql on your computer. Read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html) for more.

Comment: I don't have MySQL server installed on my PC :/

Comment: Ok... It is written: 
"As indicated by the warning, to turn off the nonstandard behaviors, enable the new explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable at server startup."
What is the file that I should change and where is it placed ?

Answer (score 0):

if u r using mysql 5.6 and getting
 "[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated".
when u use mysqld in commandline, just don't worry, don't panic...
What u have to do is go in start menu-> programs-> mysql-> mysql server 5.6-> mysql commanline client.(Windows) 
u will be asked to enter password, enter ur root password.
then u will see 
mysql>
start creating database directly
Try it its simple, but will solve ur problem... it solved mine!